# website on iPad safari, when I touch on button 1, button 2 is triggered

Tags: javascript, css, safari, frontend

I've been facing a strange issue, the position when I click (using mouse or touch) on my website on safari (iPadOS 16.5 not always, sometimes it happens) is wrong.

For e.g. when I click on Button 2 --> Button 1 is clicked instead of Button 2. I think all clickable areas are moved down.

Have any of you guys faced this issue before? How did you solve it?
Thank you very much!

[My website UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tMIFZ.png)